# SQL - Removing Duplicate Rows but Keeping Null Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Happy New Year SO!

**Problem**

I'm writing a stored procedure that takes in a list of User Ids and it should return 1 record **per user id** that contains:

1. User details from the `User` table (first name, last name etc)
2. Latest modified address record from the `Address` table. If there IS NO `Address` record, then we need to return `NULL` in the address fields (`Address`, `Postcode` etc)
3. Country details from the `Country` table (Region etc)

Now I have the following, which is correctly returning NULL's for no address details (last record in the screen shot) BUT for a User Id that has multiple address records, I'm having multiple records returned and NOT the lastest modified address record:

```
SELECT  
    U.Id, U.FirstName, U.Surname, U.Email, U.DateOfBirth,
    AD.AddressLine1, AD.AddressLine2, AD.AddressLine3,
    AD.PostCode, AD.Nickname, AD.Phone, AD.Modified,
    CNT.Name, CNT.Code,
    a.MaxDate
FROM 
    @TableVariable AS List
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Users AS U ON List.Id = U.Id
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Addresses AS AD ON U.Id = AD.User_Id
LEFT JOIN  
    (SELECT  
         JA.User_Id, MAX(CONVERT(DATE,JA.Modified,10)) AS MaxDate
     FROM dbo.Addresses AS JA
     GROUP BY JA.User_Id) A ON (AD.User_Id = A.User_Id AND CONVERT(DATE,AD.Modified,10) = A.MaxDate)
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.Countries AS CNT ON AD.Country_Id = CNT.Id
ORDER BY 
    AD.Modified DESC
```

Here is the result set after running the above. As you can see I have correctly got my record returned for a User WITHOUT an address (Last record) but I'm getting 3 records for 2108 when I wanted 1, inlcuding the latest modified address (AD.Modified).

[image]

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use outer apply and order by to get the latest record, with something like this:

```
FROM @TableVariable AS List
    LEFT JOIN dbo.Users AS U
        ON List.Id = U.Id
    OUTER APPLY  (
        SELECT top 1 *
        FROM dbo.Addresses AS JA
        WHERE U.Id = JA.User_Id
        order by Modified DESC
    ) AD
    LEFT  JOIN dbo.Countries AS CNT
        ON AD.Country_Id = CNT.Id
    ORDER BY AD.Modified DESC
```